# Statistical tables in a Delphi program

Tags: delphi

Does the Math unit or some other unit allow us to access statistical tables from within Delphi?  For instance, if I want the F table value for a level of significance of 0.05, and 2, and 10 degrees of freedom, I type in FINV(0.05, 2, 10) in Excel and get 4.1028.  Is there something like that in Delphi? Thanks.

Comment: [`SDL Component Suite - Statis`](http://www.lohninger.com/statis.html) will probably do the job. Other possibility is to code the function yourself. Or look at this, [`AlgLib F Distribution`](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/distributions/f.php).

Comment: Cool the AlgLib stuff even has a Delphi download!

Answer (score 0):

Delphi does not ship with anything of that nature. You'll need to find third party code.

Whenever I'm faced with implementing something like this I do this:

- Find some Fortran 77 code
- Convert it to C with f2c -a
- Compile to an object file with a C compiler
- Link statically with $L

A simpler approach would be to compile to a DLL but I avoid that for ease of distribution.

Comment: OK.  Clearly, that is beyond my present capabilities.  So I have to think of another way.  Thanks, @David.

Comment: Downvote? Strangely this is the only answer that actually addresses the question that was asked: *Does the Math unit or some other unit allow us to access statistical tables from within Delphi?*

Comment: @David Actually, yours is +not+ the only answer that addresses the question, because the other questions also provide links to Delphi units that do provide statistical tables. (The question does not specify that it has to be units that ship with Delphi.) [But no idea why the downvote.]

Comment: @PhiS asking for links to third party libs is off topic

Answer (score 0):

I have personally had a lot of good experience with the [TPMath/DMath library](http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/jean.debord/tpmath/tpmath.htm) to provide statistics functionality in Delphi. This library claims to provide similar functionality as the widely known [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/), but since I certainly have only ever used a small subset of its functionality, I don't know if it really fulfils that promise.

Anyway, if I understand you correctly, you are specifically talking about the [F distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution), and as far as I can see from the TPMath manual, it looks like it contains relevant functions (I am assuming it is the one under "Snedecor's distribution").

I am not entirely sure, if it is the same as Excel's `FINV` function, but my first guess would be that you'd want to have a look at this one [quoted from the manual]:

> `Function InvSnedecor(Nu1, Nu2, P)` returns the value X such that
>   Phi(nu1,nu2)(X) = P.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source Pascal/Delphi [AMath](http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/misc_en.html#amath) library has many statistical distributions with PDF, CDF and InverseCDF (i.e. quantile functions); see here for a list of the [implemented distributions](http://www.wolfgang-ehrhardt.de/amath_functions.html#statdist), your F table values can be computed with

`f_inv(nu1,nu2,y):    the functional inverse of the F distribution, nu1, nu2 > 0, 0 <= y <= 1`

In your case the third parameter is 1 - level of significance, the double function returns

`F_Inv(2,10,1-0.05) = 4.1028210151`